# Adding clients to Keycloak for a system with one mobile app, one angular app, one api gateway and 4 other Micro services

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices, keycloak, openid-connect

In my project, there is a mobile app, an angular web app, 4 micro services and one api gateway. The users with role 'agent' can enroll customers using the mobile app. The web app is for users with role 'manager' to see the customer data and finalize on the customer enrollment.

1. Here, if I want to set up Keycloak for authentication, should I add
   every micro service as a separate client ?
2. Should I add mobile app and web app as separate clients in keycloak ?

Answer (score 2):

**CLIENTS**

The web and mobile app must be registered as separate OAuth clients. They will have a client ID but no client secret since they are public clients. They will use PKCE and have different redirect URIs, eg:

- Web: https://www.example.com/callback
- Mobile: com.example.app:/callback

**APIs**

By default APIs do not need to be registered as clients. In most setups related microservices can just forward JWT access tokens to each other, as explained in the [scopes](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/) article. This is a secure way to maintain the user identity.

APIs sometimes act as clients though, eg if they need to do something like create users in Keycloak programmatically. Identity systems provide [User Management Endpoints](https://curity.io/resources/learn/user-management/) to enable this.

So one of your APIs, eg a Users Microservice, may need to be registered as a client. It would use the client credentials flow to get an access token with a SCIM related scope.

**GATEWAY**

It is common, and recommended, for a gateway to act as an introspection client. This enables data in access tokens returned to internet clients to be kept confidential. Read more about this in [the phantom token pattern](https://curity.io/resources/learn/phantom-token-pattern/).

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me the insight. One query regarding high availability of gateway service. Currently, I have set up one gateway service where rate limiter, filtering, circuit breaker pattern etc. is specified there. But, if I set up 2 instances of api-gateway service, how can I configure it to make sure that rate limiter works perfectly by considering 2 instances running at the same time ?